# Spring AMQP and RetryTemplate

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a RabbitTemplate configured with a RetryTemplate in the following way:

```
@Bean 
public RabbitTemplate myRabbitTemplate() 
{
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(myConnectionFactory());
        template.setChannelTransacted(true);

        template.setMessageConverter(myMessageConverter());
        template.setReplyAddress(MY_RESPONSE_PRIVATE_QUEUE);
        template.setQueue(MY_RESPONSE_PRIVATE_QUEUE);
        template.setMandatory(true);
        template.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        template.setExchange(MY_REQUEST_EXCHANGE);
        template.setBeforePublishPostProcessors(new MyMessagePostProcessor());

        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        template.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        template.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(new DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor());

        return template;
}
```

Doing connection tests using TCPView and WireShark, I think that in one of the connection cuts one of the sent messages has been duplicated (I guess by the configuration of the RetryTemplate).

Throughout the project there have been other connection failures and errors (ShutdownSignalException, TimeOut ...) and we have never detected duplicate messages. 
Under what circumstances is the sending of the message re-attempted?

Thank you

***EDIT 11/03/2019***

Now I have a little more information about the repeated messages. During the sending of the message (and before receiving the ACK), a connection error occurred:

```
06-03-2019 10:09:52.919|WARN |com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler|120||AMQP Connection XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX|An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:868)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:858)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleFailure(AMQConnection.java:681)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$400(AMQConnection.java:47)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:582)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
```

The server receives two messages with the same spring_listener_return_correlation but different spring_request_return_correlation:

```
spring_listener_return_correlation=0475d6f3-4859-418d-93fe-ed96fb28e733, spring_request_return_correlation=2926

spring_listener_return_correlation=0475d6f3-4859-418d-93fe-ed96fb28e733, spring_request_return_correlation=2927
```

Can the configuration of the "RetryTemplate" be the cause of this duplicate shipment?

Thanks

Comment: You may have an exception already after send confirmation from the RabbitMQ. Or you may use request-reply feature some weird way... We need to see a simple project to play with to determine an issue...

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with an example project. It has only happened once in the production environment, and it is rather a theoretical question. If we have configured a retry policy with "RetryTemplate", could it be the case that two instances of the same message were sent (for example, with slow connection problems)?